# Time count - from frontend to backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm thinking to make a simple timer, so when the timer is clicked, the time starts to count and then I can stop it and the time passed will be saved into the DB.

But there's some tricks to it, as I figured out:

1) When the tab(of the current timer) is switched to another, the time count isn't trusty, due the low priority on the inactive tabs.

2) How can I varify the time passed with PHP in backend? (I've thought of making AJAX call every XX seconds to varify it with backend, but how can I make counter like this in my backend with PHP? Is this even possible using PHP?

P.S. I don't mind to drop legacy browsers, but I want to support all the modern ones(except the Edge :) )

Comment: What have you tried already? Any example code?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit vague, but I'll try to answer it the best I can.

What I think is that you could be using a timestamp on the first click, and compare it with the second time the timer was clicked, this will not be affected by the "background" tab problem and will be easy to make.

Then you subtract times, and then you have how much time passed, without having to bother about incrementing times with the event loop, which is where I think this is all going wrong.

You could even go "crazy" and make the clicks just call the backend, and there have all the timestamps for everyone, so that the computation of the time is always trusty, but still, it should be just a simple problem of **date subtraction**

Also forget the thing with calling the backend every second and such, cause it would be a massive effort that wouldn't actually solve your problem, the event loop isn't trusty in the foreground.

**NOTE:** Also, next time better share a snippet with the community so that we can understand better what are your concerns and what have you tried before and is not working.

**NOTE2:** This timer shouldn't be used for important matters, security wise if timestamps are retrieved from the client they can be cheated. **As a general rule, NEVER trust the client in the backend** (Obviously, when talking about important actions that could ruin your business, EG money transfers, tickets, and such)

Comment: It can be noted though that this timer shouldn't be used for important matters such as security if timestamps are retreived on client-side, because it can be cheated by changing the client device time settings. Calling the backend is more reliable, but less precise because it will take account of the request time.